# beginners guide for php htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have just started learning htaccess.

And i want to test one  page :

I have one folder called "favs" and inside that i have a php file index and from that i am passing to the page gallery.php with querystring ID

so the url will be :

```
mainsite.com/favs/gallery.php?id=7
```

Now i want the url to be like :

```
mainsite.com/favs/7
```

and this is the code i write in .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ gallery.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ gallery.php?id=$1

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is your question? Is the rewrite not working? Is it behaving differently to what you wanted?

Comment: Hi it doesn't work when i use the url as mainsite.com/favs/7 it should be display the page mainsite.com/favs/gallery.php?id=7 but it shows me page doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are wrong. You have this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ gallery.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ gallery.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

`^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$` will match *everything* in the URL after the first slash, as long as there is no slash. There's a slash in `mainsite.com/favs/7`, so the rule doesn't match, and it looks for an actual directory named `/favs/7`. What you want is to match only the piece after favs, like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^favs/([0-9]+)/?$ favs/gallery.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

The code above is what you should put in .htaccess if it is in your root directory. If it is in your /favs directory, then you need to remove the `/favs` from RewriteRule and add a `RewriteBase` like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /favs
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ gallery.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

*Note: based on your question, I have eliminated letters, `_`, and `-` from the regular expression. If you need to match them, you can tweak the rule above accordingly.*

Comment: It sounds like you have this .htaccess in your root folder, but want to redirect to favs/gallery.php. I have edited my answer accordingly; please try it again.

Comment: Hi sorry to trouble , but still its not working.. let me show you the whole code : this is my url : http://www.fullridescholarships.net/favs/ and this is my code

Comment: Please clarify "not working" -- this works just fine on my testing server.

Comment: Also, please confirm that the page `/favs/gallery.php` actually exists. If it doesn't, you can't redirect to it; you'll get a 404 if you try.

Comment: Kindly check i posted whole code . and yes the gallery page is exist there here is the url http://www.fullridescholarships.net/favs/gallery.php?id=7

Comment: Please post the code in your question; it doesn't show up in the comments.

Comment: I have edited my answer, because it's not clear where your .htaccess file is. See if that addresses your issue.

Answer (score 0):

the is my full code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]



RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^favs/([0-9]+)/?$ favs/gallery.php?id=$1

</IfModule>
```

and this is the url :

```
http://www.fullridescholarships.net/favs/
```